# Is there a way to execute HTTP response body as a javascript code?

Tags: javascript

Actually I know there is a way to do that as I have made one implementation of it as seen here:

```
function sendSearchRequest(searchQuery, getFiberStatus, prepopulateCity, zip){
    var fileref = document.createElement('script');
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://52.16.32.189/FIBIA_Autocomplete_v2/getData/?search=" + encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)+"&getFiberStatus="+getFiberStatus+"&prepopulateCity="+prepopulateCity+"&zip="+zip);
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
```

However this appears to be 10 times longer than the time required to get an actual response from the server.

This is the example request:

```
http://52.16.32.189/FIBIA_Autocomplete_v2/getData/?search=1052&getFiberStatus=false&prepopulateCity=true&zip=null
```

It returns some JSON data as well as some functions that I would like to call as callback. It works well, but it's too slow.

Any common design pattern you could suggest here? How can I execute HTTP response as JavaScript code on client?

**EDIT:**

Actually I have figured it's not this that is causing the extreme delays, it's some kind of Tomcat caching or warming up or something related to server not being ready the first time there is a request made (and it's not browser caching).

Comment: why would you want to do that? why not define the callback functions in your actual script and just request the data?

Comment: Honestly I don't see how that would increase the speed. I'd do what Simon suggested but I'm still not sure it will change the performance.

Comment: I think it's okay that parsing your data as script is longer than just downloading this data.

Comment: @Simon I was thinking about it the same. The problem is that I have several data sets and if I don't want to make separate call for each, I did it this way.